# the minimum installer for .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, installation

i made an app in C# with .NET framework 4.0.

what is a most minimum install solution for me?

I don't care that the solution can include .net 4 Client Profile into install package or not. (of course, if the solution impossible to including, the solution should guide a user to download framework via Microsoft website. It's better if this progress perfrom background/automatically.)

I think InstallShield is too heavy for me.

**edited**

Note : I can't use ClickOnce. I want to distribute a installer by single package file. (*.msi, *.exe ,...)

Comment: Right-click the Solution, Add, New Project.  Other Project Types, Setup and Deployment, Setup project.  Right-click the new Project node, Add + Project Output, select your project.  Done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you consider to be the "most minimum." If you're just looking for something with the smallest possible footprint, but don't care if it's difficult for users, you can just provide a zip file. I wouldn't recommend it, though.

For ease of use, I'd recommend the ClickOnce installer that comes with Visual Studio. It's easy for you to set up, it pretty much automatically handles updates from a web server if you want it to, and the install process is pretty much just a single click from a website. Unfortunately, that click won't work if .NET isn't installed on the client's machine, so it won't automatically install the .NET framework. I get around this by having the download site instruct users to go to the Microsoft site and install the framework.

#### Update

Based on your new requirements, you may want to look at the [Nullsoft Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net). I've never used it, but I've seen it recommended and their website advertises:

> It is designed to be as small and flexible as possible

So maybe that would be a good fit for your needs.

Comment: clickonce is great - it makes a forms apps as maintainable as web sites. you forget all about problems of versioning you had in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Without sounding like a product advertisment, our company have switched from Installshield to Tarma Installer, it's pretty cheap but not free, it is really quite easy to create, and the file project file is all XML, so it's pretty good in sourcecontrol.

You could also look at [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), the installer for WinAmp, there are so many choices.

You could try these too http://www.google.com/search?q=installer+products+free